# Why does list classes in local OrientDB console hang?

Tags: orientdb

I am trying to run `list classes` from the console:

```
orientdb {db=mydb}> list classes


CLASSES
```

But it hangs here indefinitely and then when I interrupt it:

```
Jul 07, 2020 10:02:27 AM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
WARNING: Received signal: SIGINT
Jul 07, 2020 10:02:27 AM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFO: Orient Engine is shutting down...
Jul 07, 2020 10:02:27 AM com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager log
INFO: - shutdown storage: wdb2...
```

It works fine if I ssh to the server and run the console there but if I run the console locally then it doesn't work.

Selecting the classes from the schema metadata works in both cases:

```
orientdb {db=mydb}>select expand(classes) from metadata:schema
```

The only thing that I can think of is perhaps I am missing something on the classpath as I am running the `orientdb-tools` JAR myself.

Any ideas?

Comment: which version and operating system?

Comment: OrientDB 2.2.31 (I also tried 2.2.37) and macOS Catalina 10.15.5

Comment: these versions are very, very old.  2.2.37 was released in September 2018. My suggestion is to first move to  3.1.x (https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/releases/tag/2.2.37)

Comment: 2 years is not old when talking about database software. I have finally upgraded to 3.0.x after several failed attempts and many other problems (3.1.x is not GA). Sadly a lot of the issues I have are still there.